# Magento: Send SMS to customer on each order status change

Tags: php, magento, sms

How can I send a SMS to a customer as soon as the status of his order changes, from pending, processing or/and complete.

Im using php magento, Im trying to send customers sms whenever an order is being placed, and i want an sms to be sent on each change in the order status. The problem is if i put the message outside the event condition, i get an sms, but if i put in $order_status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, there are no sms

You can see what I've tried below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if ($order_status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
{
  $message   = "Dear Customer, Your order is being processed";
}

if ($order_status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)
{
  $message   = "Your order is complete, Pls expect the delivery";
}
```

Comment: When asking a question tags should give a general idea what the question is about; not down to the specific details, as in this question about orders and states, but furthermore about the technologies and frameworks used. This makes it easier for experiences user to find your question and aid you.

Additionally for this question you should provide the concrete problem. What isn't working? Is it creating an error? If so, what does the error say? Otherwise what is going wrong?

Comment: Im using php magento, Im trying to send customers sms whenever an order is being placed, and i want an sms to be sent on each change in the order status. The problem is if i put the message outside the event condition, i get an sms, but if i put in  $order_status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, there are no sms

Comment: Use the *edit* link at the bottom of your question to provide additional information; that makes it easier visible for everybody.

Comment: Checkout this one https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 2):

**I Found answer on the same website:**

There are free modules available like "Spring Edge Magento sms extension" which is Compatible with: Magento versions 1.x, 2.x

Magento sms module events configuration :

*When Order is placed. * When order status is set to hold. * When order status is set to Unhold. * When order is cancelled. * When order status is set Shipment.

[SMS Integration with Magento API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729179/sms-integration-with-magento-api)