# SMS Integration with Magento API

Tags: api, magento, sms, magento-1.8

I am using Magento 1.8.1 and I want to integrate SMS with our store.

I have an API URL of SMS but don't know how and where to put that URL in Magento.

They provide me this code:

```js
<?php 
class sendsms
{
  private $api_url;
  private $time;
  private $unicode;
 private $working_key;
 private $start;
 private $sender_id;
 public  $api;
 public  $wk;
 public  $sid;
 public  $to;

 /**function to set the working key
  * 
  * @param string_type $wk:helps to change the working_key
  */
 function setWorkingKey($wk)
 {   
  $this->working_key=$wk;
 }
 
 /**function to set sender id
  * 
  * @param string_type $sid:helps to change sender_id
  */
 function setSenderId($sid)
 {   
  $this->sender_id=$sid;
 }

 /**function to set API url
  * 
  * @param string_type $apiurl:it is used to set api url
  */
 function setapiurl($apiurl)
 {  $this->api=$apiurl;
   $a=strtolower(substr($apiurl,0,7));
    
    if ($a=="http://") //checking if already contains http://
    {
     $api_url=substr($apiurl,7,strlen($apiurl));
     $this->api_url=$api_url;
     $this->start="http://";
    }
      elseif ($a=="https:/") //checking if already contains htps://
    {
     $api_url=substr($apiurl,8,strlen($apiurl));
     $this->api_url=$api_url;
     $this->start="https://";
    }
    else { 
       $this->api_url=$apiurl;
            $this->start="http://";
       }
 }

 /** function to intialize constructor
  * 
  * @param string_type $wk: it is working_key
  * @param string_type $sd: it is sender_id
  * @param string_type $apiurl: it is api_url
  *          used for intializing the parameter
  */
 function __construct($apiurl,$wk,$sd)
 {
  $this->setWorkingKey($wk);
  $this->setSenderId($sd);
  $this->setapiurl($apiurl);
 }

 /**
  * function to send sms
  * 
  */
 function send_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml")
 {
  $this->process_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml",$time="null",$unicode="null");
 }

 /**
  * function to schedule sms
  * 
  */
 function schedule_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml",$time)
 { 
  $this->process_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml",$time,$unicode='');
 }

 /**
  * function to send unicode message
  */
 function unicode_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml",$unicode)
 {  
  $this->process_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url,$type="xml",$time='',$unicode);
 }

 /**
  * function to send out sms
  * @param string_type $to : is mobile number where message needs to be send
  * @param string_type $message :it is message content
  * @param string_type $dlr_url: it is used for delivering report to client
  * @param string_type $type: type in which report is delivered
  * @return output  $this->api=$apiurl;
  */
 function process_sms($to,$message,$dlr_url="",$type="xml",$time='',$unicode='')
 {  
  $message=urlencode($message);
  $this->to=$to;
  $to=substr($to,-10) ;
  $arrayto=array("9", "8" ,"7");
  $to_check=substr($to,0,1);
 
  if(in_array($to_check, $arrayto))
   $this->to=$to;
  else echo "invalid number";

 if($time=='null')
  $time='';
 else
  $time="&time=$time";
 if($unicode=='null')
  $unicode='';
 else
  $unicode="&unicode=$unicode";
 
   
   $url="$this->start$this->api_url/web2sms.php?workingkey=$this->working_key&sender=$this->sender_id&to=$to&message=$message&type=$type&dlr_url=$dlr_url$time$unicode";
   $this->execute($url);
 }

 /**
  * function to check message delivery status
  * string_type $mid : it is message id 
  */
 function messagedelivery_status($mid)
 {
  $url="$this->start$this->api_url/status.php?workingkey=$this->working_key&messageid=$mid";
   $this->execute($url);
 }

 /**
  * function to check group message delivery
  *  string_type $gid: it is group id
  */
 function groupdelivery_status($gid)
 {
   $url="$this->start$this->api_url/groupstatus.php?workingkey=$this->working_key&messagegid=$gid";
  $this->execute($url);
  
 }

 /**
  * function to request to clent url
  */
 function execute($url)
 {
  $ch=curl_init();
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $output=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $output;
  return $output;
  
 }    
}
```

I am new to Magento, so please help me with the API integration.

Comment: If you are looking for OTP functionality with normal SMS notifications
Checkout this extensions
https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

For SMS Integration you need to decide what event you want to handle.

Magento Events List are available [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events).

After it you need to create observer for choosen event.

An Observer is an event handler. It listens to any event it is attached to and accordingly reacts to the event.

Your SMS API should be usen in observer. ( It is method in PHP class. )

For creating observer in Magento you need to read [this documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Comment: it need any custom module?

Comment: You need to add custom module. For handling events. For Example if you want to send SMS when order is created you need observer for sales_order_save_after event.