# Need SMS integration for magento

Tags: magento, sms, integration, magento-1.9, sms-gateway

I need to integrate SMS for different events i.e on customer registration, new order placed, order status change, etc in magento with http sms api provided by sms provider. Please share if anyone have it. I want it to be customized and dont want to use any extension for it.

Comment: See Answers from Stackoverflow - Realy helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192310/magento-sms-both-phone-verification-and-notification

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729179/sms-integration-with-magento-api

Comment: Thanks for that but I dont want to use any extension for this purpose. I need codes for it.

Comment: try this readymade extension wtih OTP functionality added https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

For Sms you need to purchase sms gateway .they provide their own curl type 
api like www.textlocal.com

and api code like

```
$token="some message";
$username = urlencode($email_id);
    $hash = urlencode($secretecode); // Get this when logged in at https://control.txtlocal.co.uk/docs/
    // Message details
    $numbers = urlencode($mobile_no);
    $sender = urlencode('Textlocal');
    $message = rawurlencode('Your activation code is :'.$token);


    $data = 'username=' . $username . '&hash=' . $hash
    . '&numbers=' . $numbers . "&sender=" . $sender . "&message=" . $message;
    // Send the GET request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.txtlocal.com/send/?' . $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  
echo $response;
```

Comment: Ya I have it but I really dont know how to integrate it with magento for new order and order shipped massages.

Comment: I bought the code for the same from a developer. Thanks